# How to format Data Table exported to pdf?

Tags: datatables

Please help me to add CSS to the export PDF using Data Table. The exported PDF is not formatted as the HTML table.I need to make td align right in exported pdf.Also how can I merge columns?

Thank you

Here is my code:

```
$('#reporTable').DataTable({

    "paging" : false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info" : false,
    "searching" : false,

    dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    tableTools: {
    "sSwfPath": "/javascripts/js/dataTables/tools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",

    "aButtons": [
    {
    "sExtends": "pdf",
    "sTitle": $filename,
    "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
    "sPdfMessage": $out_name+":" + msg
    },

    ],

    }

    });
```

Comment: You want to apply  css to export pdf button Right?

Answer (score 1):

Use `exportOptions` of data table.

For details, please visit [data table formatting](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/outputFormat-function.html)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this links for Customisation of the datatable buttons

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/className.html

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/customisation.html